# Dropzone not working in safari and IE 8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am using the dropzone in my project .it is working fine in firefox and in google chrome.
But when i test it in safari and ie 8 it is not working.
when i select the image then it stops on the ajax file and shows the ajajx file url in address bar.

the url is like this `http://localhost/wall/modules/gallery/ajax.php?page=gallery`

and my dropzone area look like this ,please see the image url

```
http://awesomescreenshot.com/08d2pwvj2f
```

my jquery code for this is:

```
//function for messages onclick upload image button
$(document).ready(function(){
//e.preventDefault();
//var new_album=$(".album_name").val();
//var selected_album=$(".selected_album").val();
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
if($("div#dropzonefrm .msg_up_img").hasClass('dropzone'))
{
$("div#dropzonefrm .msg_up_img").remove();
}
else
{
$("div#dropzonefrm").html("<div class='msg_up_img'></div>");
$("div.msg_up_img").addClass('dropzone');
$("div.msg_up_img").dropzone({ url: "modules/gallery/ajax.php?page=gallery" ,acceptedFiles : ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.JPEG,.JPG,.PNG,.GIF", });
var sendingHandler = function(file, xhr, formData) {
    //formData.append('album_name', $(".album_name").val());
    //formData.append('selected_album', $(".selected_album").val());
};
$('div.msg_up_img').each(function() {
    Dropzone.forElement(this).on('sending', sendingHandler);
    Dropzone.forElement(this).on("success", function(file,response) {

     alert(response); //The response
     $(".last_insert_id").val(response);

});

});
}
});
```

my html is:

```
<div class="gallery_cnt">
<a href="#" class="new_album_txt">Create New Album-:</a><input type="text" style="display:none;" class="album_name" value="" placeholder="please enter Album Name"/>
OR <a href="#" class="album_slct_box" style="display:none;">Click here select album</a>

<?php stream_img_upload($con,$page); ?>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg add_img_to_gall">Add image to album</button>
</div>
```

here is the my php function that i called in html

```
function stream_img_upload($con,$page)
{
$user_id=$_SESSION['id'];
$album_name_query=mysqli_query($con,"select album_name,id from album where login_id='$user_id'");


echo '<span class="gallery_name_display" ><select class="selected_album" name="album_slct">
<option value="">Select Gallery</option>';
while($album_name_query_result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($album_name_query))
{
$album_name=$album_name_query_result['album_name'];
$album_id=$album_name_query_result['id'];
echo '
<option value="'.$album_id.'">'.$album_name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select></span>';
echo '<div>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">Title<input type="text" class="img_ttl"/></div>';
echo '<div>Description<input type="text" class="img_desc"/></div>
</div>';
echo '<div class="gallary_upld_cnt">';
    echo '<span class="up_resp"><input type="hidden" class="up_img_resp" value=""></input><input type="hidden" class="cmt_img_resp" value="" mid=""></input></span>';
    echo '<div id="dropzonefrm" ></div>';
echo '</div>';
}
```

now i have show all code so please help me..

Your are the rock and genious friends.

please help me for this problem i have spent a lot of time but no result.

thanks in advance and please ask me if something is not clear.

Comment: First things on problems: Check the **validation** of your HTML (http://validator.w3.org/). Second: Check the console in the browser - Any errors?

Comment: Hello Adrian it is working good in chrome and firfox but the problem is with safari and IE 8.i check the html and console ..it is ok

Comment: Yes it works in Chrome & FF, but each browser handle/rendering the HTML different - Depending on the engine. Without code we can only speculate on your problem. Please tell us a concrete source-code, give us an example that demonstrate the problem otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: ok see the code in question posting..

Comment: Please a full HTML. I need to check it and i can't with 2-3 lines of code. Best solution: Open your site and save it via Browser (File > Save Page as,..)

Answer (score 3):

Dropzone does not support IE before version 10 or Safari before version 6.  See http://www.dropzonejs.com/#browser-support which says:

> As a side note: I have received various «complaints» about not
>   supporting earlier versions of Internet Explorer – some even called me
>   an IE hater. Although I don’t really object to that, the reason I do
>   not support earlier versions of IE is very simple: IE up until version
>   10 does not provide the required APIs to implement only a fraction of
>   what Dropzone aspires to do. If I were an IE hater, I wouldn’t
>   implement IE10 either. But IE10 actually supports the APIs Dropzone
>   requires, so it’s supported. It’s as simple as that. (The same goes
>   for earlier versions of Firefox, Opera and Safari but those browsers
>   have a good conversion rate and nobody uses Firefox 3.5 anymore. Why
>   some people still use IE8 is beyond me.)